# Pass data with one way binding to md dialog

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-material

I want to pass data to an md dialog, and if I change that data inside the md dialog controller, it should not reflect that change in the parent controller of the md dialog.

```
vm.openAddWorkstreamDialog = () => $mdDialog.show({
   templateUrl: 'main/my-dialog/my-dialog.html',
   controller: 'MyDialogController',
   bindToController: true,
   clickOutsideToClose: true,
   locals: {
     data_in_dialog: data_in_parent
   }
});
```

now I want to achieve the behavior that if I make any change to the `data_in_dialog` object inside the `MyDialogController`, it should not change the `data_in_parent` object in the parent controller.
Currently if I make any change in the `data_in_dialog` object(inside `MyDialogController`) it also changes the `data_in_parent`(which is present in the parent controller of the md dialog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `angular.copy` inside `MyDialogController`

```
$scope.varInsideDialogController = angular.copy(data_in_dialog);
```